# Need to add some more fields to Reason after State is changed to Resolved

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps When Bug state is Changed to Resolved in the Reason Filed just below that I need to add few more options. Is there a way this can be achieved.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w491f.png)

Comment: How about add additional field as I said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to add more items to Reason field. Check this feature request: [Ability to customize WIT State Reason in Inheritance Process Model](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365937/ability-to-customize-wit-state-reason-in-inheritan.html)

You may add additional field with some rules, then track this field.

[image]